# How to Measure and Manage Witness Size

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development, eth-2.0

In https://ethresear.ch/t/the-eth1-eth2-transition, Vitalik wrote:

> If you are a developer, you can eliminate the largest part of
>   disruption from gas cost changes by proactively making sure you don’t
>   write apps with high witness sizes, ie. measure the total storage
>   slots + contracts + contract code accessed in one transaction and make
>   sure it’s not too high.

How, exactly, does one do this? What is the metric? What is 'too high?'

Comment: Perhaps there's a quick link to an FAQ, but could someone explain the 'best practices' for questions? I like the edits to my question made by a super-moderator and will try to follow them going forward, but I'm sure there are others.

Comment: There are general instructions on how to ask in the "Ask Question" page: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. If you have a question about the policies you can ask in the Ethereum's meta page https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com.